# Pushing two values from the database to one array

Tags: php, arrays

On line 6 I am pushing a value from the database to the array called $products. I would now like to give another value from the database (`$row->image`) to the same array which matches with `$row->name`.

Maybe it could make sense to use a two dimensional array but I don't know how to do this in this case.

```
$products = array();
foreach($_POST['selected_checkboxes'] as $value) {
    if($result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM produkte WHERE $value = 1")){
        while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
            if (!in_array($row->name, $products)) {
                array_push($products, $row->name);
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        array_push($products, 'error');
    }
}
```

The result should show me the name and the image of both values which belong together.

Comment: Is the image from `$row->image` having the same value as `$row->name`?

Comment: Your code is [open to SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: @NaijaProgrammer no, it has another value

Comment: If I changed one the 'selected_checkboxes' values to `1=1; DROP TABLE produkte; --` then that might be bad news.

Comment: Could you post input and expected output?

Comment: "I would now like to give another value from the database `($row->image)` to the same array which matches with `$row->name`", how do you intend to get the match? Is that part of the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this, assuming you already have your `$row->name` and `$row->image` matching logic sorted:

```
if (!in_array($row->name, $products)) {
   array_push( $products, array('name'=>$row->name, 'image'=>$row->image) );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I wanted!!

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this:

```
$products = array();
foreach ( $_POST['selected_checkboxes'] as $value ) {
    if ( $result = $db->query( "SELECT * FROM produkte WHERE $value = 1" ) ) {
        while ( $row = $result->fetch_object() ) {
            // if your name is unique you can do it like this,
            // if not just take $row->id as index
            if( isset( $products[$row->name] ) ) continue;
            $products[$row->name] = array( "name" => $row->name, "image" => $row->image );
        }
    } else {
        array_push( $products, 'error' );
    }
}

// if you want to have plain digits as index you can get a reindexed array
$products = array_values( $products );
```

then you will get an array like that:

```
array(//$products
  array(
    "name" => "productname",
    "image" => "productimage"
  )
);
```

Comment: Thank you, that definitely helps!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve that if you use a stdClass object.

```
$std = new stdClass();
$std->name = $row->name;
$std->image = $row->image;
array_push($products, $std);
```

Or you can change your sql query to

```
SELECT name, image FROM produkte WHERE $value = 1
```

and

```
array_push($products, $row);
```